# If the iPad mini resolution is 1024x768, will existing iPad apps already work on it?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

The iPad mini is rumored to be 1024x768 and have a 7.85" screen.

Would existing iPad apps be available on this device or would developers have to release another version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPad mini will have the same screen resolution, but bigger pixel per inch value, so all apps should work just fine.

Comment: Some apps might default to the Retina resolution for "newer" iPads and would thus fail.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how they were programmed but as most iPad apps default to the 1024x768 resolution they should work.